# Username from form is always null

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I try to create new user using form in register.html (registration process is included in UserController). In String registrationPost, there should be object newUser containing datas from form (username, password, sex, role).

When I use newUser.toString(), it shows everything except username (for example: 'PRINTED newUser: UserForm{username='null', password='mypassword', userSex=MALE, userRole=ADMIN}')

What can I do to get also username from form? Why everything is sent except one field? Please, help me, guuuuys!

Links to project:

Controller:
https://github.com/ToTomki/getinpoland/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/getinpoland/controller/UserController.java

Template:
https://github.com/ToTomki/getinpoland/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/user/register.html

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem in `UserForm.java`

```
 public void setUsername(String username) {
     this.username = this.username;
 }
```

Should be:

```
 public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
 }
```

Comment: I thought something can be with setter, but I haven't notice that when I was checkin' it. I think I did check the User twice instead of checking User and UserForm. Thank you soooooooo much!